# jQuery Week Calendar - side by side display of conflicting events?

Tags: jquery, calendar

I"m using the jQuery Week Calendar (https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki) in order to display a large number of different events.  Some (many) of these events overlap.

Is it possible to show the events side-by-side (similar to how Google's Calendar web app does it) instead of having them overlap?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and its easy to implement. 
When you are calling your calendar in jquery and are setting some of the parameters such as timeslotsPerHour etc. simply add in:

```
overlapEventsSeparate : true,
```

after you have set allowCalEventOverlap and there you go.